# Finding the largest island size (redshift)

Tags: redshift, gaps-and-islands

Current sql code will sum up all the max island sizes into one. I'm trying to only find what the max island size is.

```
 select deviceid, grp -- min(readdate) as mn, max(readdate) as mx
       from (  select deviceid, readdate, sum(case when prev_rd >= readdate - interval '1 hour' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by deviceid order by readdate rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as grp
               from (
                    select deviceid, readdate, lag(readdate) over (partition by deviceid order by readdate) as prev_rd
                    from metersWithExcess
                    order by readdate)
            ) tt
            group by deviceid, readdate, grp
           -- having mx > mn + 1 * interval '1 hour'
```

Is there a way to return back the deviceid with it's max size? I am trying to find the longest continuous hourly readings

the data looks like this:

```
    deviceid    readdate
91428   2018-08-27 18:04:42
91428   2018-08-27 17:04:42
91428   2018-08-27 16:04:42
91428   2018-08-27 12:04:42
91428   2018-08-27 11:04:42
91428   2018-08-26 20:04:42
91428   2018-08-26 17:04:40
91428   2018-08-26 16:04:40
91428   2018-08-26 15:04:40
91428   2018-08-26 12:04:40
91489   2018-08-26 06:00:49
91493   2018-08-27 06:58:44
91511   2018-08-27 12:57:01
91511   2018-08-27 10:57:01
91511   2018-08-27 09:57:01
91511   2018-08-26 23:57:01
91511   2018-08-26 22:57:01
91511   2018-08-26 20:57:01
91511   2018-08-26 13:56:59
91511   2018-08-26 12:56:59
91511   2018-08-26 10:56:59
91547   2018-08-26 16:59:07
91547   2018-08-26 15:59:07
91547   2018-08-26 14:59:07
91547   2018-08-26 11:59:07
91547   2018-08-26 04:59:07
91582   2018-08-27 12:01:45
91582   2018-08-26 19:01:45
```

in this example: 91428  would have a max size of 3
The other devices would be similar in that they will contain the max number of continuous hours